# RadGridView Edit Button Command Not Binding in Prism 4.1 Silverlight 5

Tags: mvvm, telerik, telerik-grid, prism-4

As per my requirement I have have an Edit Button / Hyperlink in Row & in Header Row I should have a Add New Button / Hyperlink in my RadGridView Control.These buttons will load a child Window Popup for Add / Edit of Data. My Application is in Silverlight 5 with Using Prism 4.1 & MVVM (model in responsible for creating View approach).

I created a Button Like this:

```
  <telerik:GridViewColumn  Width="80">
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <telerik:RadButton DataContext="{Binding DataContext ,ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                           prism:Click.Command="{Binding AddUserEventCommand}"
                                           Content="Add User">
                           <!-- <Image Source="../../Assets/Images/icon_user_add.png" 
                               Cursor="Hand" Stretch="None" Width="32" Height="32"/>-->
                        </telerik:RadButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.Header>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadButton prism:Click.Command="{Binding DataContext.EditUserEventCommand}">
                            <Image Source="../../Assets/Images/icon_user_update.png" 
                               Cursor="Hand" 
                               Stretch="None" Width="32" Height="32" >
                            </Image>
                        </telerik:RadButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

But my click event is not working?

when I gave the same Button out side the Grid it worked for me.
whose code is like this :

```
   <telerik:RadButton Command="{Binding AddUserEventCommand}" Content="Add User" VerticalAlignment="Top"></telerik:RadButton>
```

As per few threads I found that DataContext may be the issue.
https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/64514
So I try changing the DataContext for Add Button by :

```
 DataContext="{Binding DataContext ,ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
```

**But still No success.**

Both EditUserEventCommand ,AddUserEventCommand are DelegateCommand.

In My ViewModel code is like this :

```
  public class UsersTabViewModel : TabViewModelBase , IUsersTabViewModel
{
  /// Constructor
  public UsersTabViewModel(IUsersTabView view):base(view) {
        this.Header = "Users";
        this.Title = "Users";
        this.IsSelected = true;
        ctx = new UserRiaDomainContext();
        fillUser();
        doEventBinding();
    }

  private void doEventBinding() {
        AddUserEventCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddUser, CanAddUser);
        UpdateUserEventCommand = new DelegateCommand(EditUser, CanEditUser);
    }
  ///  Bind with User Add
    private DelegateCommand _addUserEventCommand;
    public DelegateCommand AddUserEventCommand
    {
        get { return _addUserEventCommand; }
        set
        {
            _addUserEventCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AddUserEventCommand");
        }
    }

    ///  Bind with User Update in Grid Row
    private DelegateCommand _updateUserEventCommand;
    public DelegateCommand UpdateUserEventCommand {
        get { return _updateUserEventCommand; }
        set {
            _updateUserEventCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UpdateUserEventCommand");
        }
    }        
     ......
   }
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got it working After More and More Reading About Call Stack.

As My ViewModel & View binding are Constructor Injected so StaticResource wasn't the solution for me. I need to find the Ancestral DataContext to get my Command Binding.
so I did like this:

```
 <telerik:RadButton Command="{Binding DataContext.AddUserEventCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                           Background="Green" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="14" Padding="10,5,10,5">
                           <Image Source="../../Assets/Images/icon_user_add.png" 
                               Cursor="Hand" Stretch="None" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        </telerik:RadButton>
```

This way Button got Bind as per Parent DataContext and Command started working.